# Loading multiple gpx files with leaflet

Tags: php, leaflet, loading, geojson, gpx

I started using Leaflet for organizing my gpx files combined with Mysql/PHP.
I read the gpx files with the plugin [leaflet-gpx](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/leaflet-gpx).

All is working well see 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs65r.png), but the loading takes longer and longer.
Every gpx files is read out one after an other and displayed on the map:

```
var gpx0 = '0.gpx';
window.gpxfile = new L.GPX(gpx0, {async: true, polyline_options: {
                  color: '#ff0000',
                  ...
                  }
}).addTo(gpxlayer);

var gpx1 = '1.gpx';
window.gpxfile = new L.GPX(gpx1, {async: true, polyline_options: {
                  color: '#ff0000',
                  ...
                  }
}).addTo(gpxlayer);

...
```

I was wondering if there are better ways for loading or preloading somehow.

I already tried to cluster the gpx tracks with the [Marker clusterer plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) combined with the [leaflet-omnivore plugin](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore).
but I don't manage to get the lines to dissapear, only the markers are processed [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILDXn.png).

I hope some of you could help me with some tips or tricks to get everything loaded faster. Maybe you know good examples or had same problems before?

What's best for performance? using omnivore, leaflet-gpx or first converting my GPX files to GeoJSON and loading the GeoJSON files in my leaflet application?